# Numerical computation of the derivative of a curve valued in $\operatorname{Diff}(\mathbb{R}^2)$

Tags: computer-vision, image-registration, finite-differences

Assume we have a (discretized) sufficiently smooth curve $\alpha : [0, 1] \to \operatorname{Diff}(\mathbb{R}^2)$. Further assume that this curve is generated via a large deformation diffeomorphic metric mapping (LDDMM) given the endpoint diffeomorphisms $\alpha(0)$ and $\alpha(1)$. Namely, this is a two-dimensional image registration. Since this is within a computational setting, every point (diffeomorphism) along the curve $\alpha$ is extracted as the integral of a time-varying velocity field $v$ with respect to time:
$$
\alpha(t) = \int_0^tv(\mathbf{x}, t)\,dt, \text{     for $0 < t \leq 1$}.
$$
Clearly, the integral from $t = 0$ to $t = 1$ returns the full diffeomorphic registration between the source and target images. Hence, the data that I have is not the diffeomorphisms $\alpha(t)$, but rather the values of $v$ for discretized timesteps $\Delta t$. Given this, I'm interested in computing the derivative $\alpha'(t)$ for some time $t$. How would I go about doing this using the data I have? I assume that it's not as simple as computing finite differences on the velocity fields. Moreover, how would I go about computing the norm $\vert\vert\alpha'(t)\vert\vert$?

Comment: Hi gian! As far as I can remember from **Calculus - I**, the *dummy variable* of an integral (which is $t$ in yours) cannot exist either in its *limit* or at the *output*... May be you should write it with a new dummy variable. Because this is a difficult question otherwise.

Comment: and you'll really need to choose between *discretized* and *smooth*, far as I can tell: the terms are mutually exclusive, unless you use these terms differently than analysis usually does. *Diffeomorphisms* map between two differentiable manifolds: that literally says that neither in- nor output of your function take only discrete values?